# Assign pointer value

Tags: c, pointers

Why do I get exception in the code?

```
char* first = "first";
char* second = "second";
*first = *second;
```

Shouldn't it just assign values?
Error message says: access violation

Comment: `first` and `second` point to memory that you must not write to. Unfortunately, the conversion to non-constant pointer types is performed when initializing. Please, for the future, also provide the exact error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083488/dereferencing-pointer-to-integer-array

Comment: That's unrelated, I would say @ChristianSarofeen.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt There is no conversion from `const` to non-`const` in the posted code. `"first"`, although it must not be written to, has type `char [6]`, and decays to `char *` when assigned.

Comment: Shame on anyone who voted to close as a duplicate of a C++ question.

Answer (score 0):

No because they are string literals and are read only

```
char *first = "first";
char *second = "second";
```

you can try with arrays instead.

```
char first[] = "first";
char second[] = "second";
```

to prevent this kind of error you can do this

```
const char *first = "first";
const char *second = "second";
```

when declaring string literals, it will not prevent the problem completely because you still can cast away the `const` but you should do so conciously.

Comment: Technically, string literals are not unmodifiable. It's just that writing to them constitutes *undefined behaviour.*