# Pointer to Array confusion

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

### By definition, it is a pointer variable that points to an array.

my code print the values of three element array .
**my question** why the result is right using`printf("Value at %p = %d\n", ptr2arr +i, *(ptr2arr[0]+i));`
and wrong result except the first value while using `printf("value at %p =%d\n" ,ptr2arr+i,*(ptr2arr[i]))`

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    int (*ptr2arr)[3];
    int i;
    ptr2arr = &arr;
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
    printf("Value at %p = %d\n", ptr2arr +i, *(ptr2arr[0]+i));
    }
    printf("-------------------\n");
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
    printf("value at %p =%d\n" ,ptr2arr+i,*(ptr2arr[i]));
    }
   return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: I get a compilation error for `ptr2arr = &arr;`. `cannot convert 'int (*)[4]' to 'int (*)[3]' in assignment   ptr2arr = &arr; `.

Comment: @chmike works with only a warning in C, in C++ you need to match the type. I guess it's just a typo, `int arr[4]` should be `int arr[3]`.

Comment: thnks i corrected the error

Comment: you seem to be thinking that `array[index]` is the same thing as `array + index`. it's not. rather, it's the same thing as `*(array + index)`.

Comment: It's better to use '&ptr2arr[i]' rather than 'ptr2arr+i'.

Comment: why it is better to use   '&ptr2arr[i]' rather than 'ptr2arr+i'?

Comment: The `%p` specifier requires an argument of type `void*`. If you're printing a pointer of another type, you should cast it. You can probably get away without the cast on most systems, but there's no guarantee that `void*` and other pointer types have the same representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `ptr2arr[0]` is the same as `*ptr2arr`, so it dereferences the pointer to array of 3 `int`s, giving you effectively the array `arr`.  Therefore, `*(ptr2arr[0] + i)` is the same as `*(*ptr2arr + i)` is the same as `*(arr + i)`, which gives you the correct result.

Whereas in the line

```
printf("value at %p =%d\n" ,ptr2arr+i,*(ptr2arr[i]));
```

`ptr2arr[i]` (syntactic sugar for `ptr2arr + i`) "jumps" over arrays of 3 `int`s,  so dereferencing it `*(ptr2arr[i])`  gives the `arr[0]` only when `i = 0`, otherwise it gives you what's located at the address `arr + 3*sizeof i` (undefined behaviour).

---

PS: the address passed to `printf` should be `*ptr2arr + i`, not `ptr2arr + i`.

See also [dereferencing pointer to integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083488/dereferencing-pointer-to-integer-array) for a bit more details.

Comment: in your 3rd line answer  arr+i   is equivalent to &[i] in this example not arr[i]