# Matrix contamination in C

Tags: c

I am new to C and I don't understand why I am not able to easily populate a 2d array.

Here is my code: one function populates the matrix and the other displays it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int matrix[5][5];
int size = 5;

void fill_matrix() {
    for(int k=0; k<size; k++) {
        for(int l=0; l<size; l++) {
            matrix[k][l] = k + l;
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix() {
    for(int k=0; k<size; k++) {
        for(int l=0; l<size; l++) {
            printf("%d ", *matrix[k,l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    fill_matrix();
    print_matrix();
}
```

And the result is this

```
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4
```

Instead of this

```
0 1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 6 
3 4 5 6 7 
4 5 6 7 8
```

I know that the answer is probably extremely simple, but I was't able to find a solution after few hours so here I am.

Comment: `*matrix[k,l]` -> `matrix[k][l]`. Bonus: [Comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Don't forget the star at the beginning of the "before" to make it clear it doesn't belong in the "after"

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You are right

Comment: Note that `*matrix[k,l]` is the same as `matrix[l][0]`, which is why each output row you printed was `0 1 2 3 4` - the value of the 0th elements of the individual rows. (OK, not quite, but the explanation is a bit much for a comment...)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Maybe this question deserves an answer after all...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Go ahead.  I'm not sure I could explain it in a way that's easily understood.

Comment: Not me, got to AFK.. Anyway already VTCed as typo :)

Comment: Well, this is related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083488/dereferencing-pointer-to-integer-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you meant to do was `matrix[k][l]` to address the row and column of the matrix.

Instead, what you have, `*matrix[k,l]`.  What is happening here is the comma operator is being used in the expression to index the array.  The result of the expression is equal to that of the right-side of the comma operator, so effectively what you have is `*matrix[l]`.  `matrix[l]`, using only one index for a two dimensional array, points you to the `l`th row of the array, so it is essentially of type `int[5]`.  Then when you dereference it with the asterisk, you are grabbing the contents of the first element of that row.

Comment: Indeed, I was confused by the fact that no warning was coming from the compiler about the comma syntax (that is valid in some languages). I thought it was some kind of Pythonic copy error and that the first row was replicated throughout the whole matrix. Thanks